# What are DOMDocument namespaces for?

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument, xml-namespaces

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('slash', 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/');
```

From what I understand they act like document definitions, and are required to identify certain XML elements.

Does PHP actually do a request to that URL and verify if the element exists in the document definition?

Because that URL shows a [404 not found](http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash) page :(

```
$result = $xpath->evaluate('string(//atom:entry[3]/slash:comments)');
```

Could this be the reason why I get an empty string, while trying to retrieve the value of the `<slash>` element from a RSS feed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> $xpath->registerNamespace('slash', 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/');
> ```
>
> From what I understand they act like document definitions, and are required to identify certain XML elements.
>
> Does PHP actually do a request to that URL and verify if the element exists in the document definition?

**No.**
That [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) identifies an [XML namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace), that represents an XML vocabulary. Such namespaces are designed to cope with different contexts using the same term with different meanings. With namespaces, a single XML file can contains tags and attribute with the same "name", that are qualified via a prefix. For example you can have a xml document like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xmlns:human="http://sample.xml.com/Human">
  <title>John Smith measures.</title>
  <body>
    <human:name>John</human:name> <human:surname>Smith</human:surname>
    is <human:height unit="feet">6</human:height> feet tall.
  </body>
</html>
```

In such content the "human" prefix is used to mark elements from the **http://sample.xml.com/Human** namespace and the empty string (that is the default prefix) is used to mark elements from the **http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml** namespace. These URI are namespace identifiers, not schema locations (that can be expressed with either [DOCTYPE declaration](http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/doctype_declaration.shtml) or [XML Schema instance](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance)). It's a good practice to provide proper documentation of the namespace at the location identified by the namespace URI, but it's not required (indeed the xhtml namespace URI points to the related W3C documentation, but the RSS extension you are looking for, doesn't).

Note however that both `resolveExternals` and `validateOnParse` can affect the download of DTDs or schema definitions referred by the target xml, but **not** namespace documentation. By no means, any parser would download such a documentation, since it's intended for human consumption.

> ```
> $result = $xpath->evaluate('string(//atom:entry[3]/slash:comments)');
> ```
>
> Could this be the reason why I get an empty string, while trying to retrieve the value of the  element from a RSS feed?

**No.**
First, check that the source xml contains the correct xmlns declarations and that it contains a `<slash:comments>` node inside the **third** atom entry (note, the third, because **xpath indexing is one based**, so that `//atom:entry[1]` means each entry that is the first in its own parent node, `//atom:entry[2]` the second and so on).
If so, I suspect that you forgot to register the **atom** namespace.
Try something like this (adapted from the users' contribution to [DOMXPath::registerNamespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php#91538) documentation):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml); // your xml string here
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$xpath->registerNamespace('atom', "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
$xpath->registerNamespace('slash', 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/');

$result =  $xpath->evaluate('string(//atom:entry[3]/slash:comments)');
```

You can see this running at http://codepad.org/JX8RpaKu

Indeed, to use qualified xpaths, you need to register the default namespace too.

Answer (score 2):

You have got multiple questions. I will try to address them one by one:

> ```
> $xpath->registerNamespace('slash', 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/');
> ```
>
> From what I understand they act like document definitions, and are required to identify certain XML elements.

Yes, whenever you have an XML document with namespaces, then each element can be in it's own namespace.

If you want to access elements in their own namespace, then yes, you need the namespace to identify them. E.g. within the Xpath expression.

In PHP XML Namespaces are supported by DOMDocument and the other libxml based XML extensions.

> Does PHP actually do a request to that URL and verify if the element exists in the document definition?

No, for the code-example you give:

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('slash', 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/');
```

PHP will *not* request that URL. You already have noticed that the URL is empty / gives 404 so you might want to understand what this is all about. That URL in fact is an URI. That is the difference being and *Identifier* and a *Locator*.

[image: The URI Pill: Can be URL or URN]

To have XML namespaces working, nothing needs to be located. The namespace only needs to be identified. Hence a valid XML namespace can be represented with any URI. For example, `fantasy:space` is a valid URI and does fully qualify the requirements to specify an XML namespace. But when you enter it in your browser you won't even get any server-response back (your browser does not know what "fantasy" stands for).

So the 404 you get is not the reason why the slash is empty with your Xpath evaluation:

```
$result = $xpath->evaluate('string(//atom:entry[3]/slash:comments)');
```

The reason why you get an empty string here is a different one. See the Xpath expression:

```
string(//atom:entry[3]/slash:comments)
```

That is asking for the string value of a node-set. You have specified the node-set as:

```
//atom:entry[3]/slash:comments
```

[Getting a string of a nodeset](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string) in PHP DOMDocument means:

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the [string-value of the node](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) in the node-set that is first in document order. If the node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

As the node is an element, the string-value of [the element node](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#element-nodes) means:

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.

So there are two explanations here why you get an empty string: Either the node-set is empty or the elements string-value is just an empty string.

You can quickly learn about the number of nodes inside a node-set by using the [`count()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-count):

```
$result = $xpath->evaluate('count(//atom:entry[3]/slash:comments)');
```

Which then should give you a better idea which of the two cases is the case. As you have not shared the source XML it can not be said *why* specifically however it - as I would assume - contains no nodes. Seeing the source should clarify this easily.

Until then, I can only guess that you are probably parsing an RSS 2 feed that does not contain `<atom:entry>` elements but just `<item>` elements. See my example:

```
$feed = 'http://hakre.wordpress.com/feed/';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($feed);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//item[3]/slash:comments)'); # 1
```

It outputs the value "1" as comment count for the third item. This is the feed of a standard Wordpress blog. [I have put this online as an interactive example, so you can see it in action and enter your feed URL](http://codepad.viper-7.com/L5MURC).

BTW: If you create the `DOMXPath` object *after* you've loaded the XML, you don't need to register the namespace-URIs as long as you know which prefixes are used in the document. This is why in the example I do not register any namespace-URI.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to retrieve the content of namespaced nodes,  have you tried [getElementsByTagNameNS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php)?

```
$dom - new DOMDocument($url);
$slashEls = $dom->getElementsbyTagNameNS('slash', 'slash'); // Assuming the element is <slash:slash> in the XML
foreach($slashEls as $slash) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a tutorial on namespaces, 13 years old but still useful, see

http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm